# Spring MVC + SpringJPA - runtime error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, datasource

I'm having runtime problem with Spring JAP application. I have defined the data source. The error message is as follow:

```
Info:   [EL Info]: 2015-03-13 21:31:40.932--ServerSession(1884324141)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
Info:   [EL Info]: connection: 2015-03-13 21:31:41.339--ServerSession(1884324141)--file:/C:/Users/smoczyna/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/classes/_default login successful
Info:   [EL Warning]: metamodel: 2015-03-13 21:31:41.371--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
Info:   [EL Warning]: metamodel: 2015-03-13 21:31:41.809--The collection of metamodel [ManagedType] types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.  The lookup on [class org.squadd.sampledb.entities.Customer] will return null.
Info:   [EL Info]: connection: 2015-03-13 21:31:41.825--ServerSession(1884324141)--file:/C:/Users/smoczyna/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/classes/_default logout successful
Severe:   Startup of context /SampleDb-WEB failed due to previous errors
```

The problem is I'm not using `Persistence.xml` at all, I have data source defined in `applicationContext.xml` this way:

```
...
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/META-INF/sample-db.properties"/>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>
...
```

Comment: "The problem is I'm not using Persistence.xml at all" - so why don't you add a `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Because I don't want to. It bring a tone of other issues. When I changed the data source class from: "org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" to "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" the error message changed: Couldn't find a destroy method named 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource' but "destroy-method="close" is there. Any help out there?

Comment: The snippet you have posted has no relevance to the exception. post your full config file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/META-INF/sample-db.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>        
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.squadd.sampledb"/>

    <!-- NOTE: Do NOT use the "PersistenceUnit" property, it will override the "PackagesToScan" -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.squadd.sampledb.repositories"/>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
                <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/> -->
                <property name="database" value="DERBY"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>                
                <entry value="static">
                    <key>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING"/>
                    </key>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.squadd.sampledb.repositories"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29042690/edit) your question to include information. Do not post an answer unless you actually have an answer to the question.